# Concat string from list of strings with some condition

Tags: algorithm

Let say I have this array

```
["kamila", "maciej", "jut", "akik", "agrak", "kandom"]
```

this array has specific property, every element from this array can be used to create one big concatenad string for example here

akikkamilaagrakkandommaciejjut

we can join two strings if last letter of first is the same as first of second string,

e.g

(apple, elevator) => appleelevator.

I want to concatenate all words in this way (we are given that it is possible)

My tries:

I wanted to create map which contains first and last letter as a key and list of strings satisfying this condition, and while processing get word from this list and concatenate to resultant string, but problem is I don't really know from which word should I start.

Sorry for my english, I am not native

Comment: an algorthmic code is enough for you?

Comment: @SandrinJoy prefer java, but sure i think its ok

Comment: sorry , i did a pseudocode similar to python

Comment: each tab space is equal your java brackets

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: i made a simple change to increment the position value , or else it becomes an infinte loop.

Comment: In your first example, the array has 7 words, but the output string only has 6 words. You should [edit] the question to fix the example. Also, don't accept an answer that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, so you have 1 word that ends with `a` and 2 words that start with `a`. So 1 of the words that starts with `a` must be the first word. Both of those words that start with `a` end with `k`, so it doesn't matter which one you pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          li=["kamila", "maciej", "jut", "akik", "agrak", "kandom"]
          string=""
          x=0
          while(True):
              if (string=="" or string[len(string)-1]==li[x][0]):
                string+=li[x]
                li.pop(x)
                x-=1
              if len(li)==0:
                break;
              if (li[x][len(li[x])-1]==string[0]):
                t=li[x]
                t+=string
                string=t
                li.pop(x)
                x-=1
              if len(li)==0:
                break;
              if x==len(li)-1:
                x=0
              else: 
                x=x+1

          print(string)
```

Comment: In beggining of while loop you are setting position = 0; in the end you are doing position+1; does it hava sense?

Comment: pos=0 , it should be outside the while .my bad, sorry

Comment: also , you have to re-arrange the list after incrementing the position.Taking the first element into 2nd position and last element to first and so on

Comment: After execute your code I got axxy, did i something wrong?